# How to prevent SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] switches to the calling page?

Tags: php, http-referer, http-host, getenv

Please help.
A link obtained by using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in form.php like this:

```
<?php
$link = 'http://' . getenv('HTTP_HOST') . '/';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) and !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$refData = parse_url($link); }
if($refData['host'] !== 'domain.com') {
die("server error"); }
?>

<p>Send this link - <?php echo htmlentities($page_url, ENT_QUOTES); ?></P> 

<input name="link" type="hidden" 
value="<?php echo htmlentities($page_url, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

When the form is submitted, the referer url switches to *form.php*. Is it something wrong with this code or Are there any specific ways to prevent the referer url from being switched?

Comment: don't use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in such a way it is browser set and completely unreliable (mine is always blank)

Comment: What do you expect? the Referer is the page you came FROM. If you're on page A and click a link that leads to page B, then your referer is page A. Once on B, you click a link to C, then your referer is now B. It's not the page you started out on, it's not the page you were on 20 pages ago. It's exactly page N-1

Comment: I actually expect page A when click on a link on page A leading to page B. But when it is obtained and submitted from a form in page B or when page B is reloaded, although I have not gone to other pages at all, it turns to the page B url. How to remain the page A url without changing when page B is loaded or when the form is submitted in page B?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already pointed out, it works as it should.

You could use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to temporarily store the referrer there when the user comes to your site for the first time.

```
<?php
session_start();

// ...

if( !isset($_SESSION['referrer']) ){
    $_SESSION['referrer'] =  parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

// ...

if( $_SESSION['referrer'] !== "domain.com"){
    die("Server Error");
}
```

Comment: I tried adding session as suggested. But the url still switched to the processing page itself after submitting the form.